# Assign a temporary value to a variable in a loop python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, dictionary

I have a list of items that I need to bubble sort. The bubble sort criteria is if item `j` is ranked higher than item `i` in a majority of result sets, swap item `j` with item `i` in `FullList`. I have a very simple bubble sort figured out except for one small problem. I get a key error when the `FullList` item doesn't appear in one of the result sets. I need to put in a value to compensate for that or else my loop becomes very complicated with numerous if statements. If I could assign a token value such as 20 to any value that doesn't exist in the dictionary, my loop will be perfect. Can anyone help me out?

```
FullList = [B,C,A,D,H,E,F,G]

Results1 = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4,'E':5}
Results2 = {'B':1,'D':2,'G':3,'F':4,'E':5}
Results3 = {'C':1,'D':2,'B':3,'A':4,'H':5}

Pseudo Code:

switch = True
while(switch):
switch = False
    for i in range(len(FullList)-1):
        if FullList[i+1]<FullList[i] in Results1 & 2:
           FullList[i],FullList[i+1] = FullList[i+1],FullList[i]
           switch = True
        elif FullList[i+1]<FullList[i] in Results1 & 3:
             FullList[i],FullList[i+1] = FullList[i+1],FullList[i]
             switch = True
        elif FullList[i+1]<FullList[i] in Results2 & 3:
             FullList[i],FullList[i+1] = FullList[i+1],FullList[i]
             switch = True

Key-Error: 'A' not in 'Results2'
```

Comment: What does the question title have to do with the question description?

Comment: @abarnert I am trying to assign a temporary value to a variable in a loop in order to do something with it. I think it is a suitable title?

Comment: @adohertyd: I retracted my answer because your code and your understanding of it requires more help than linking a simple function to solve your issue. You can try to get help by joining the #python IRC channel at freenode.net.

Comment: Is this homework?  Because in Python you wouldn't usually write a bubble sort, you would usually use the built-in sorting code.

Comment: @steveha no it's not homework I'm just very new to python so a lot of its nuances are strange to me. I'm trying to implement a part of a specific algorithm that requires a bubble sort according to the paper that I am basing my code on

Comment: @adohertyd: It shouldn't matter what sorting algorithm you use, as long as it's a stable sort.

Comment: @JoelCornett true but I think that I would prefer to write my own sort method, for practice and so that I know exactly what's happening. Thanks for the input though

Comment: What temporary value are you talking about? FullList[i+1], FullList[i], and True are all values that live outside the scope of the list. Even if they were temporary, the exact same syntax you have would work exactly as well as it does (e.g., you could write `switch = not False`, and it wouldn't change anything). And it's hard to see how that could affect the actual error you're getting.

Comment: @abarnert `Results2` does not have the value 'A' so if I try to compare the value of 'A' with another value in `Results2` I get a key error. I needed to attribute a temporary value to 'A' for `Results2` for comparison. It can be discarded then

Comment: OK, you're assuming the only way to avoid the key error is to assign a temporary value for 'A' to Results2, and then discard it. I'll leave aside the fact that Results2['A'] is not a variable, and the fact that it's in a loop is completely irrelevant; the reason this is confusing is that, rather than stating what you're trying to do and asking for help doing it, you gave us a half-formed guess at how it might be accomplished, and made everyone guess what you were actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but seems like `get(key[, default])` is what you need, you can check out the details of this [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

In your case, `Results2.get('A', 20)` will give you 20

Comment: This is what nightcracker gave me but I'm not always going to know what keys are missing. The data in this program is user generated so I need to be able to assign a value to any missing key, not specific ones

Comment: @adohertyd In the sample code above, whatever key(not necessarily 'A') doesn't exists in `Results2`, it will return 20

Comment: so to clarify; if I replace `Results2.get('A',20)` with `Results2.get(key,20)` in my loop, it will return 20 for any key that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the dict's `get` method when fetching the rank, you can provide a default value for when the key is absent.